# How to write search stored procedure for searching based on name, businessname, universityname in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to search a table based on name, businessname, universityname, skillname.

Suppose I will search one time by name, another time by businessname, another time universityname likewise, but when when I enter a name I click search button I will show right. But when I enter businessname or universityname I not getting properly I will getting like businessname column all are empty like null.

I have written a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchPeople_test]
(
      @FirstName nvarchar(255),
      @Location nvarchar(100),
      @MembershipUserID uniqueidentifier,
      @UniversityName nvarchar(255),
      @Postcode nvarchar(20),
      @BusinessName nvarchar(255),
      @AssociateMemberID uniqueidentifier,
      @SkillName nvarchar(255),
      @Debits int,
      @Gender int
  )
AS
BEGIN

    SET @SkillName = [dbo].[fnGetMemberskills](@AssociateMemberID)
    SET @Debits = [dbo].[fnGetMembersSpentCredits](@AssociateMemberID)
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT  DISTINCT  AssociateMember.ID AS ID       
        ,AssociateMember.Firstname AS FirstName        
        ,AssociateMember.Lastname AS LastName
        ,Address.Location AS Location
        ,Address.City AS City
        ,BusinessProfile.BusinessName
        ,EducationHistory.UniversityName
        ,AssociateMember.MembershipUserID AS MembershipUserID
        ,EmploymentHistory.JobTitle AS JobTitle
        ,AssociateMember.MemberPhotoUrl AS MemberPhotoUrl
        ,aspnet_Membership.Email AS Email
        ,AssociateMemberJourneyContent.JourneyContent AS JourneyContent
        ,([dbo].[fnGetMemberskills](AssociateMember.ID))  AS MemberSkillList
        ,([dbo].[fnGetMembersSpentCredits](AssociateMember.ID))  AS Debits              
FROM 
    AssociateMember 
INNER JOIN
    aspnet_Membership 
    ON AssociateMember.MembershipUserID=aspnet_Membership.UserId 
left outer join  MemberAddressLink      
    ON AssociateMember.ID=MemberAddressLink.MemberID

left outer join
    Address 
    ON Address.ID=MemberAddressLink.AddressID 

left outer join 
    EmploymentHistory 
    ON AssociateMember.ID=EmploymentHistory.MemberID     

left outer join   
    EducationHistory 
    ON EducationHistory.MemberID=AssociateMember.ID 

left outer join  
    MemberEmploymentHistory 
    ON AssociateMember.ID=MemberEmploymentHistory.MemberID

left outer join 
    BusinessProfile 
    ON BusinessProfile.ID=MemberEmploymentHistory.BusinessProfileID 

left outer join
    MemberSkill 
    ON MemberSkill.MemberID=AssociateMember.ID

left outer join 
    SkillType 
    ON SkillType.ID = MemberSkill.SkillID AND MemberSkill.MemberID=AssociateMember.ID
left outer join
    AssociateMemberJourneyContent
    ON AssociateMember.ID=AssociateMemberJourneyContent.AssociateMemberID

where
((Address.Location)=ISNULL(@Location,Address.Location) and (MemberAddressLink.IsDefault=1)
                 OR (Address.Location like '%'+ @Location+'%')or (Address.Location is null) ) and

 (AssociateMemberJourneyContent.JourneyContentTypeID=1 OR  AssociateMemberJourneyContent.JourneyContentTypeID IS NULL) AND


(((BusinessProfile.BusinessName)=ISNULL(@BusinessName,BusinessProfile.BusinessName) 
                             OR (BusinessProfile.BusinessName like '%'+@BusinessName+'%')or(BusinessProfile.BusinessName is null))
                              AND
                             ((MemberEmploymentHistory.StartDate)=(SELECT  MAX(StartDate) FROM MemberEmploymentHistory 
WHERE MemberEmploymentHistory.MemberID=AssociateMember.ID) OR (MemberEmploymentHistory.StartDate IS NULL))) AND


((AssociateMember.Firstname)=ISNULL(@FirstName,AssociateMember.Firstname) 
                          OR (AssociateMember.Firstname like '%'+@FirstName+'%')OR (AssociateMember.Firstname IS NULL)) AND 



((Address.Postcode)=ISNULL(@Postcode,Address.Postcode) 
                 OR (Address.Postcode like '%'+@Postcode+'%') OR (Address.Postcode IS NULL)) AND

(((EducationHistory.UniversityName)=ISNULL(@UniversityName,EducationHistory.UniversityName) 
                OR (EducationHistory.UniversityName like '%'+@UniversityName+'%') OR (EducationHistory.UniversityName IS NULL)) AND
            ((EducationHistory.StartDate)=(SELECT  MAX(StartDate) FROM EducationHistory 
WHERE EducationHistory.MemberID=AssociateMember.ID) OR (EducationHistory.StartDate IS NULL) ))AND



((AssociateMember.GenderID)=ISNULL(AssociateMember.GenderID,@Gender) 
                          OR (AssociateMember.GenderID IS NULL)) AND


((EmploymentHistory.StartDate)=(SELECT MAX(StartDate) FROM EmploymentHistory 
WHERE EmploymentHistory.MemberID=AssociateMember.ID)OR (EmploymentHistory.StartDate IS NULL)   ) 
end
```

Comment: Can you please show us a small dataset that you're getting now and a small dataset that shows what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Well rather than trying to do it all in one hit, break it down, first write your query for on column, run it. Then do it for the next, run it. Etc then finally combine the two queries, run, combine 3 queries run etc. If at any point you dont get what you expect, analyse what you are doing.